# Problem with a step involving a type of Riemann integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I am reading this text, [image]

, and I find it unclear how the ratio of the considered rectangle's area to its length tends to become the derivative of a function $S$ as the lenght of the considered rectangle tends to zero. It seems to me that the area of an arbitrary rectangle has emerged into a function $S$ which is then used to derive the integral of $f(x)$. Can anyone show me how and why this works?

Comment: I think it's just how we define differentials. They ($\text{d}S$ and $\text{d}x$) are numbers s.t. the approximation $y \cdot \Delta x \approx \Delta S$ becomes exact.

Comment: @Khallil But in the last step they are treated as a function, so how can they be numbers and a function?

Comment: I'm slightly confused now, but I was always under the impression that the final line was obtained by ('integrating') summing both sides of the equality over the differential $\text{d}x$ and rewriting the $y$ as $f(x)$ (which is what we defined it as) which would give: $$\int \dfrac{\text{d}S}{\text{d}x} \text{ d}x = S = \int y \text{ d}x = \int f(x) \text{ d}x$$

Comment: @Khallil Sorry for my incomputable ignorance, what I had been considering was that $\frac{dS}{dx}$ is a real number, and thus, when integrated results in an algebraic function.

Comment: I'm not too sure of what you mean, but I always considered variables like $x,y,t \dots$ as numbers. Forgive me for just saying 'numbers' in my first comment!